# How to create an instance of a class having the type of this class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing kind of an online store and have `Admin` class where I want to add new employee:

```py
class Admin():
    __employees = []
    def __add_employee(self, name, surname, salary, employee_type):
        new_employee = Employee(name, surname, salary)
        self.__employees.append(new_employee)
```

in `employee_type` parameter I want to pass one of `Employee` abstract class implementation (`Driver`, `Consultant`, etc). But in listing above it only creates `Employee` class instance.

```
class Driver(Employee):
    pass


class Consultant(Employee):
    pass
```

How can I add certain implementation of `Employee` such way?

Comment: I think you are looking for the [Factory Pattern](https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/)

Comment: @Tomerikoo in Python the factory pattern is builtin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Admin():
        __employees = []
        def __add_employee(self, name, surname, salary, post):
            if not issubclass(post, Employee):
                raise ValueError("Invalid post")

            new_employee = post(name, surname, salary)
            self.__employees.append(new_employee)
```

You can send the class object itself when as a parameter to the `__add_employee` method

```
__add_employee("john", "10000", Driver)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `post` as a constructor for a new employee
`__add_emloyee`

```
class Admin():
    __emloyees = {}
    def __add_emloyee(self, name, surname, salary, post):
        new_employee = post(name, surname, salary)
        self.__employees.append(new_employee)
```

Answer (score 1):

> in post parameter I want to pass one of Employee abstract class realization (Driver, Consultant, etc). But in listing above it only creates Employee class instance.
>   How can I add certain implementation of Employee such way?

Err... What about using the `post` parameter ????

```
class Admin():
    # preferably use a single leading underscore (convention for
    # "implementation" attributes, ie "protected"), 
    # there are __very__ few real use cases for 
    # `__private` attributes

    _emloyees = {}

    # 1. make te method public so we can use it
    # 2. rename 'post' to something meaningfull
    #    (here you want to pass a class)
    # 3. and of course: __use this param__

    def add_emloyee(self, name, surname, salary, employee_type):
        new_employee = employee_type(name, surname, salary)
        self.__employees.append(new_employee)

# and pass the correct class, of course
a = Admin()
a .add_employee("foo", "bar", 200000, Consultant)
```

**This being said**, there are quite a few issues with your design.

The first one is a canonical misuse of inheritance. You are mixing invariant data (the employee's name etc) with variant ones (the position of an employee at a given point in time). Being a "driver" or "consultant" or whatever is not like your birthdate, it's just the **current** position of an employee, so you want to split this in one class holding invariant data (name, birthdate etc) and a second one representing it's current position (driver etc).

The second issue is with using a class attribute as storage for your employees. Not only will you loose all your data between two runs, but, most important, this doesn't work well with how a typical web ("online") app is deployed in a production environment, which typically uses a multi-process scheme (and possibly even a multi-servers, each running multiple process) and arbitrarily dispatch requests to just any of the available processes (or even starts a new one), so you'll never keep your data in sync with this. That's why we use distinct database server processes for data storage...

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes, I must agree with all of statements. But I will not deploy it anywhere. It just a laboratory work for studying UML and architecture.

Comment: @PavelAntspovich and this is indeed typical of the totally inane design examples found in UML or similar "textbooks" (looks like people writing those "textbooks" have never ever wrote a real application). FWIW I kind of suspected something like this, and as far as I'm concerned it's a very compelling reason to point out those flaws - if you want to learn "architecture" (the hype word for "basic design") at least learn things that make sense in the real world ;-)